# Is Laravel5 supported on shared hosting environment?

Tags: php, laravel-5, shared-hosting

One of the biggest strength of PHP has been the hassle free deployment of PHP web applications on shared hosting environment. And despite PHP being a complete crap, maximum content on Web is in PHP because  of the ease of deployment with PHP. But i have read a lot of posts discussing issues with deploying Laravel5 applications on shared hosting. If Laravel5 is not meant for shared hosting then Django or Rails are much better  frameworks to stick too. I would like to know if from people who have deployed Laravel5 app on shared hosting environment,

Is Laravel5 compatible with shared hosting environment?
Does one necessarily need to install anything on shared hosting or just copying files form devbox to hosting environment enough?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to just copy the stuff from your Dev environment to the server.

If you have SSH access on the shared host it's still possible to use composer directly on there (I have it on my setups and I simply love it.)

There is [this forum post](http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting) discussing some of the problems with Laravel 5 on shared host

Comment: Thanks Kasper!! I wanted to hear it from horse's mouth. Since you have already done it, i  am sure i can easily pick Laravel5 without the fear of paying for VPS and dedicated hosting solutions. But I do not have enough reputations to up-vote your answer :(

Comment: Some hosts gives access to a jailed SSH (it's an option in Cpanel/WHM) so you might just ask your hosting priovider if you can get SSH access (in a jailed environment)